# getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo() api level 10

Tags: java, android, mobile

I need to establish the highest recording output of the camera, usually I do getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo() for > 3.0 however I need to support this in api 10.

Is there an alternate way to get this information?

Comment: Have you tried `get("preferred-preview-size-for-video")`? I realize it's hacky but it may be possible on APIs under 11. You can also try printing out the value of `flatten()` to see if the value you need is in there.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo()` is just a convenience method whose result depends on `getSupportedVideoSizes()`, which has been around since API level 5. The documentation states:</strike>

> the preferred preview size (width and height) in pixels for video
>   recording if getSupportedVideoSizes() does not return null; otherwise,
>   null is returned.

So as alternative, just call `getSupportedVideoSizes()`, check the result isn't `null`, sort the result by highest number of pixels and you should have what you're after. For the sorting part you'll want to set up a `Comparator<Camera.Size>` and use `Collections.sort(...)`.

---

**Edit:** Seems like I was looking at the API level of the wrong method! :( Unfortunately, above won't be of any further help...

Comment: `getSupportedVideoSizes()` seems to have been added in API 11 based on the documentation.

Comment: @A--C: Yuck, I can't believe I was looking at the API level of the wrong method! :( Thanks for pointing this out. Unfortunately, above won't be of any help to the OP in that case...